# Webscraping historical data from twitter

Tags: web-scraping, twitter

For a research project, I want historical tweets of like past 4-5 years from twitter. Is there qny problem in webscraping data from twitter? Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter just announced a new [Academic Research Track](https://developer.twitter.com/en/solutions/academic-research) for early access to their Twitter API v2. They have a new [Full Archive Search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all) endpoint that might be what you need.